# How to read in variables from txt file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, text-files

I have file `dane.txt`, how to read this in MATLAB ? Which function to use ? `load()` give me message about unequal number of columns in first and second row.

```
File Number; rho; B; drop probability
21; 0.30; 20; 0.00230906
21; 0.30; 30; 0.00150975
21; 0.30; 40; 0.00110355
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at `dlmread` with delimiter `';'`, or `textscan` or `importdata`.

For example

```
 >> A = importdata('dane.txt')

A = 

      data: [3x4 double]
  textdata: {'File Number'  ' rho'  ' B'  ' drop probability'}
colheaders: {'File Number'  ' rho'  ' B'  ' drop probability'}

 >> A.data

ans =

 21.0000    0.3000   20.0000    0.0023
 21.0000    0.3000   30.0000    0.0015
 21.0000    0.3000   40.0000    0.0011
```

Comment: how to create 4 vectors of given names automatically ?

Comment: You have the names as elements of the 1-by-4 cell array `A.colheaders`